# convert object datatype to int in python

Tags: python, pandas, types

I have a variable Eg:

- VISIT_NUMBER
- 2458611-22
- 2051216-837
- 2555065-216
- 2133886-39
- 2415201-156
- 8332215-12

Which is of the type object, I want to convert it to type int.

I have tried

Dataset1['VISIT_NUMBER']=Dataset1['VISIT_NUMBER'].astype(str).astype(int)

error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2458611-22'

even astype(float) gives me the same error.

Used : pd.to_numeric(Dataset1['VISIT_NUMBER'])

ValueError: Unable to parse string "2458611-22" at position 0

Some more info about the variable :

VISIT_NUMBER             26265 non-null object

Comment: What integer to you want "2458611-22" to become?

Comment: 1) Tag your pandas question with the `pandas` tag. 2) Post a [mcve]. You can't just say _"I have VISIT_NUMBER 2458611-22 2051216-837 2555065-216 2133886-39 2415201-156 8332215-12, which is of type object"_, that's not useful information. What _kind_ of object is it?

Answer (score 0):

int size is limited.
In case of python 32bit:

```
>>> sys.maxsize
2147483647
```

you can check int's max size using sys.maxsize.

that is why the representation in your case is `2458611-22`
in addition, python doesn't know to convert this format to int. (because you have `-22` in the string asked to be converted

Comment: Hi, is there a way that i can convert this type to int of float ? the value in my variable has a - followed by numbers.
sys.maxsize output 9223372036854775807

Comment: you can do something like this:`value=str('2458611-22')` then `value2=value.replace('-', 'e-')` and then `float(value2)`